# How to use a cast value of one field as a default for another field in Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

Edit: I guess what I'm asking is how to do:
`board.members[1].username = owner`

I'm trying to make `owner` of the object (input by user) be among its `members`, which is a map linking a member name to its role, both being strings. This should happen as the new object is created.

Edit: my sorry attempt at making it simple

```
defmodule Vision.Boards.Board do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "boards" do
    field :members, :map
    field :owner, :string
    field :team_name, :string
    field :title, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(board, attrs) do
    board
    |> cast(attrs, [:title, :owner, :team_name])
    |> validate_required([:title, :owner, :team_name])

    board =
      Repo.insert! %Board{members: %{:owner => "Manage"}}
  end
end
```

Also, this `field :members, :map, default: %{:owner => "Manage"}`

Comment: It would be helpful if you include some code of what you have tried.

Comment: @Everett It's too embarrassing. `board = Repo.insert!(%Board{members: %{:owner => "Manage"}} ` in `def changeset(board, attrs) do` just below `|> validate_required(... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with Repo.insert you are immediatelly jumping to the database ... why not something like

```
board
    |> cast(attrs, [:title, :owner, :team_name])
    |> validate_required([:title, :owner, :team_name])
    |> put_change(:members, %{:owner => "Manage"})
```

of course in order to handle different behaviour that could/should be extracted to the function and called in the same way ... but for simple create this should do.

Comment: Great, that looks simple enough. However, I am unable to test it. I keep getting this error: `Protocol.UndefinedError at GET /boards
protocol Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented for %{"owner" => "Manage"} of type Map.` Even though, I git hard-reset to an earlier commit and search for that string using Sublime Text's Find in Files returns 0 results. It must be caching it somewhere and I have no clue where.

Comment: Update: after dropping the database, I figured that `|> put_change(:members, %{:owner => "Manage"})` is creating a problem. I'm guessing because the app is not configured to display this map object.

Comment: Hard to comment without wider context, in general if there is need for a relations, then it is time for a new table... maps in fields is practically table in table ... me no like it ...

Comment: I figured a map would be simpler and I know a thing or two about them from C++. It's becoming more and more apparent that I'll be needing another table. Anyway, thanks and +1

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `Ecto` doesn't support something built-in which allows you to do this. Here's what you can do to accomplish it:

```
defmodule Vision.Boards.Board do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  
  # ..

  @doc false
  def changeset(board, attrs) do
    board
    |> cast(attrs, [:members, :title, :owner, :team_name])
    |> cast_default_members_from_owner()
    |> validate_required([:members, :title, :owner, :team_name])
  end

  defp cast_default_members_from_owner(changeset) do
    struct = apply_changes(changeset)

    if is_nil(struct.members) and not is_nil(struct.owner) do
      put_change(changeset, :members, %{struct.owner => "Manage"})
    else
      changeset
    end
  end
end
```

**Quick tip:**

Calling `cast_default_members_from_owner` after `cast` with `:members` allows you to use `%{struct.owner => "Manage"}` as a default which can be overridden in `attrs`, and calling it before `validate_required` allows you to ensure that the default value is always applied.